# What does it mean "Whoever remembers Krishna at last moment of death attains Krishna"?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

Krishna in Gita has said that whoever will remember him at the last moment of his death will attain him , without fail. (Gita 8:5 and Gita 8:6)

Gita 8:5

> Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.

Gita 8:6

> Whatever one remembers upon giving up the body at the time of death, O son of Kunti, one attains that state, being always absorbed in such contemplation.

What does this mean ? Does it mean , those who remember him at the time of his death will merge with Krishna ?

Answer (score 1):

It means those who knows the Bhagwan becomes liberated.

> *“esha vidhwan guna sreshto Vishnu parama durjaya |
> divya chakshur maha theja veekshyathe yoga chakshsha |” (MBH 13:14:9).*
>
> *“Bhishma said.: That Vishnu (Krishna) who knows every thing, who has greatest qualities, who cannot be won over by anybody, who has special holy sight, and who is greatly resplendent, always sees and remains connected (viz meditate on) him (Rudra) by his eyes of yoga”.*

> *“umaasahaayaM parameshvaraM prabhuM trilochanaM niilakaNThaM prashaantam.h |
> dhyaatvaa munirgachchhati bhuutayoniM samastasaakShiM tamasaH parastaat.h |” (Kaivalya Upanishad 7).
> “sa eva sarvaM yadbhuutaM yachcha bhavyaM sanaatanam.h |
> j~naatvaa taM mR^ityumatyeti naanyaH panthaa vimuktaye |” (Kaivalya Upanishad 9).*
>
> *“Meditating on the highest Lord, allied to Uma, powerful, three-eyed, blue-necked, and tranquil, the holy man reaches Him (Shiva) who is the source of all, the witness of all and is beyond darkness (i.e. Avidya). He alone is all that was, and all that will be, the Eternal; knowing Him, one transcends death; **there is no other way to freedom”.***

> *“vedaahametaM purushhaM mahaantamaadityavarNa.n tamasaH parastaat.h |
> tameva viditvaatimR^ityumeti naanyaH panthaa vidyate.ayanaaya |” (Svetaswatara Upanishad 3:08).*
>
> *“I know that great purusha (Rudra) of sunlike lustre beyond the darkness. A man who knows him truly, passes over death; **there is no other path to liberation”.***

That’s the reason **“Lord Dattatreya”** in his **‘Avadhuta Gita’** mentions,:

> *“indrajAlamidaM sarvam yathA marumarEchikA akhanditaM anAkaraM vartatE kEvalah shivaH”,*
>
> **which means:**
>
> ***“All this is verily illusion as like as the mirage of a desert; beyond all differentiation, beyond all forms truly there is lord Shiva alone!”***

For more info about b.g. you can check [this answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54134/20968).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 1):

*On the grounds that, a steady devotion towards God, which perfected overtime while living, culminates into  a habituated disposition of  remembering the God alone, even when senses and organs have become extremely weakened, seems to be point emphasized in various references*

**Bhagavad Gita 7.30( that sets the context for chapter 8 - sambhandhokti)
Swami Madhusudana Saraswatis Commentary**

> And it is not to be apprehended that My devotees who have attained such a status forget Me due to the failure of their organs-even at the time of death, because ye, those who; viduh,
> know, think of, mām, Me; sādhibhüta-adhidaivam, along with
> My existence in the physical and the divine planes; and sădhi-ajñam, along with My existence in the sacrifices; te, they;becoming yukta-cetasah, concentrated in mind, having their
> minds ever absorbed in Me as a result of perfection in that (habit
> of concentration); viduh, know, through My grace; mäm, Me,the all-pervading Self; prayāna-kāle api ca, effortlessly-as
> suggested by the word ca-even (api) at the time (kāla) of death
> (prayana), even when all the organs have become extremely
> Unsteady at the time of departure of life. On account of the
> Perfection of the habit (of concentration) acquired previously
> they, even at the time of death, come to have a mental modification that takes My form alone. And, as a result, they indeed
> become self-fulfilled through the Yoga of Devotion for Me. This is the idea.

**Chandogya Upanishad 3.14.1**

> सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म तज्जलानिति शान्त उपासीत । अथ खलु क्रतुमयः पुरुषो यथाक्रतुरस्मिँल्लोके पुरुषो भवति तथेतः प्रेत्य भवति स क्रतुं कुर्वीत ॥ ३.१४.१ ॥
> All this is Brahman. Everything comes from Brahman, everything goes back to Brahman, and everything is sustained by Brahman. One should therefore quietly meditate on Brahman. Each person has a mind of his own. What a person wills in his present life, he becomes when he leaves this world. One should bear this in mind and meditate accordingly.
> The Upaniṣad says here to think over this with kratu—that is, with great effort, and with deep concentration.
> Kratu also means will, or will power. It is your will that decides your destiny.The Upaniṣad says here to think over this with kratu—that is, with great effort, and with deep concentration.
>
>  [Commentary](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239005.html)  translation Swami Lokeshwarananda

**Prasno upanishad 3.10**

> यच्चित्तस्तेनैष प्राणमायाति प्राणस्तेजसा युक्तः ।
> सहात्मना यथासंकल्पितं लोकं नयति ॥ १० ॥
> Of what thought, by that he attains prana, the prana combined with udana along with the atman, conducts to the world thought of.

Sri Shankaracharyas commentary

> Of what thought he is at the time of death, by that thought, i.e., volition, he attains along with the senses, the prana, i.e., he puts forth the activity of the chief Prana. The meaning is that at the time of death, the activity of the senses having declined, he lives putting forth the activity of the chief Prana alone. Then his relations around say ‘he breathes and lives’; and that prana manifesting the activity of udana (tejas); with the atman with the owner, i.e., the enjoyer. The prana manifesting the activity of the udana alone, leads the enjoyer to worlds (bodies) thought of, according to the influence of virtuous and sinful karma
>  translation
> [Sri Sitaraman Sastry](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145316.html)

**Dr. S Radhakrishnans commentary BG 8.5**

> The importance of the state ot mind at the moment of death emphasized in the Upanisads. Chindogya, IIl, 14, 1; Prašna, I 10. We will think of God in the last moments only if we are devoted to Him previously also

**Dr. S Radhakrishnans commentary BG 8.6**

> The soul goes to that on which it's mind is set during the last moments.What we think we become.Our past thought determine our present birth and our present ones will determine the future

Answer (score 0):

It simply means they reach Krishna in afterlife, the concept is similar to reaching `Vaikunta`, `Kailasa`, `Swargalok` etc.

The second part states that what you become depends on what you believe.

If one believes they go to `Naraka loka` at the time of death, that's where they will go, and one believes they wanted to remain because of dissatisfaction, that's where they will be stuck.

Hope this simple explanation helps understand the meaning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ONLY THOSE who have achieved the POORAN BRAHM SWAROOP persona **before death** (through BRAHM NAAD & BRAHM PRAKASH experience within WHOLE BODY) can achieve a **AFTER-LIFE** unto KINGDOM OF DIVINE DIVAY **BRAHM PRAKASH** OF HARI DHAM. Here all members have HARI Swaroop.

Hari Ram; Hari Krishna; Hari sai Ram; Hari Vitthal; Hari Mandir; Hari dwar